# Annotation and its toolbar for Measure-x in High stocks is not appearing in the graph rather it is appearing in the navigator below

Tags: typescript, highcharts

I am facing a weird issue, not sure why? My annotation (the light blue shaded portion) and its toolbar is not appearing on the graph but rather on the navigator below when I am completing my measure-x event. Ideally the annotation should appear on the graph with min max and average value. However when doing measure-xy with same code it is appearing fine. I am giving my chart options below ,also the screenshot of the issue. Please help me with this as I am not able to debug it any more.

```
    const chartoptions = {
  title: {
    text: '',
  },
  chart: {
    animation: false,
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: true,
    fallbackToExportServer: false,
  },
  boost: {
    useGPUTranslations: true,
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
  },
  yAxis: [
    {
      id: '2df93b78-7622-4957-a7ec-8aa8482111a9',
      labels: { format: '{value}' },
      opposite: false,
      showEmpty: false,
      title: { text: 'kelvin' },
    },
    {
      id: 'df29ccae-94f3-4d0a-bf11-32ad7da1a2ed',
      labels: { format: '{value}' },
      opposite: true,
      showEmpty: false,
      title: { text: 'kelvin' },
    },
    {
      id: '1dda5a2f-7337-480a-a486-d778ba0f01bd',
      labels: { format: '{value}' },
      opposite: false,
      showEmpty: false,
      title: { text: 'mbar' },
    },
    {
      id: '1dda5a2f-7337-480a-a486-d778ba0f01bd',
      labels: { format: '{value}' },
      opposite: false,
      showEmpty: false,
      title: { text: 'mbar' },
    },
  ],

  navigator: {
    enabled: true,
    series: {
      dataGrouping: {
        enabled: true,
        groupPixelWidth: 2,
      },
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      showInNavigator: true,
      animation: false,
      states: {
        inactive: {
          opacity: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [
      {
        type: 'minute',
        count: 1,
        text: '1m',
      },
      {
        type: 'minute',
        count: 30,
        text: '30m',
      },
      {
        type: 'hour',
        count: 1,
        text: '1h',
      },
      {
        type: 'day',
        count: 1,
        text: '1d',
      },
      {
        type: 'week',
        count: 1,
        text: '1w',
      },
      {
        type: 'month',
        count: 1,
        text: '1m',
      },
      {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All',
      },
    ],
    selected: 6,
    inputEnabled: false,
  },
  stockTools: {
    gui: {
      buttons: ['measure', 'zoomChange', 'toggleAnnotations'],
      definitions: {
        measure: {
          items: ['measureX'],
        },
        zoomChange: {
          items: ['zoomX'],
        },
      },
    },
  },
  navigation: {
    bindings: {
      measureX: {
        end: function (e, annotation) {
          console.log('Annotation end')
        },
        annotationsOptions: {
          typeOptions: {
            label: {
              enabled: false,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    annotationsOptions: {
      events: {
        afterUpdate: function (e) {
          console.log('Annotation update')
        },
        remove: function (e) {
          console.log('Annotation removed')
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you reproduce a simplified version of this issue with the sample data on some online editor that I could work on?

Comment: Can you not use the chart options that I have provided to debug with some sample data? I am not very good with online editors and not sure if I can reproduce the same issue there? @sebastian Wedzel

Comment: this is my reproduction of your code - seems that everything works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bs92gqx5/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Yes, It is working fine in your code. That is strange, as it is the same options I am using in my code as well. Except of the fact that mine is a MultiLinegraph, that is there are multiple lines in the graph series. Also I missed one option which I am using inmy code. DO you think these can be the issue? Can you please tell in which direction should I be debugging?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the reproduction of the issue. It seems that the measure appears to another xAxis and yAxis that should be attached.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel so are you saying that there is nothing wrong with the char options that I am providing? And also how evrything is absolutely working fine when I am using measure XY? Please think of something there must be something which is going wrong. Please see the new screen shot in the updated question.

Comment: Nishit, to be honest - I don't know. I can only guess without reproduction of the issue.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel No worries,, will find out ..  Thanks by the way.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel: Hi, I am reopening the discussion as there is something I think is important to show. Please pardon me if this is much of a trouble for your team. During my mitigation of this issue , I changed the series data of my navigator thinking that there is some confusion between the axes of navigator and graph, so I provided it explicitly. After that I am getting a specific error in annotations-advanced.js. I am attaching the screen shot in my question. Please have a look , I think this might give you some idea about the issue.

Comment: I am sorry, this image doesn't say anything to me. To find a solution I need a reproduction of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating a lot, I am able to fix this issue. All I had to do was add below as an option for highcharts in my code.

```
scrollbar: {
    liveRedraw: false,
  },
```